# Use cellvalue of other column in jqgrid formatter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Can I use cell value of some other column in the formatter key of colModel.
So basically, I want to change `cellvalue --> cellvalue of some other column`.

```
    colModel.push({
        'formatter': function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            return '<a href="http://someLink/' + cellvalue + '">' + cellvalue + '</a>';
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us you have two columns `name: "mycol1"` and `name: "mycol2"` and you want to add custom `formatter` in column 1, which used the property `mycol1` of input data in the URL of the anchor and the the property `mycol1` as the text of the anchor. The code could be the following:

```
colModel.push({
    name: 'mycol1',
    formatter: function(cellvalue, options) {
        return '<a href="http://someLink/' + cellvalue + '">' +
                options.rowData.mycol2 + '</a>';
   }
});
```